# How do I put HTML tags in YAML translations for simple form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am using YML translations in a simple form. But I want to put some html tags like icons.

In the _form.haml.html is:

```
= f.input :title, input_html: {class: 'form-control'}
```

And the YAML file:

```
en:
  simple_form:
    labels:
      post:
        title: Title <span class="fa fa-globe" title="Translatable"></span>
```

But it shows just like this. Not with the icon from font awesome.
How do you I make it right?

Answer (score 2):

In your view do this to escape the html:

```
= f.input :title, label: t('.title').try(:html_safe) , input_html: {class: 'form-control'}
```

Found here: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/1232

Edit: This might make your application vulnerable to XSS, but I don't know enough to judge how much of a security risk that might be.

Comment: I was hoping for something more "automatic"... But fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the suffix `_html` on `title` so it is `title_html` in your .yml file and also call it as `title_html` in your .haml file.

note that before rails 6 there might be some differing behaviour from suffix `_html` and `html_safe`. One that I know of is, when it comes to arrays, for more [see this article](https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/rails-6-marks-arrays-of-translations-as-trusted-safe-by-using-the-_html-suffix).